# How do I check to see if a GCP service account has full access to Google Drive?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, service-accounts, google-iam

I'm trying to use a 3rd party app to retrieve files and data from Google Drive but am running into an error: `{ "code" : 404, "errors" : [ { "domain" : "global", "location" : "fileId", "locationType" : "parameter", "message" : "File not found: .", "reason" : "notFound" } ], "message" : "File not found: ." }`

I created a service account and enabled the Google Drive API and gave that service account an `Owner` role, but can't figure out if there's anything else I need to do to grant it full access to Drive. Do I need to add any scopes?

Comment: owner role of what?

Answer (score 2):

> "File not found

Means that the user you have authencated with does not have access to the file.

In the case of a service account in order for it to access a file, one of two things must have happened

1. If its a google workspace domain account, domain wide delegation must be configured and the service account should then impersonate a user on the domain with access to the file.
2. The file must be shared with the service account. This can be done by taking the service account email address and going to the google drive web application and sharing the file with the service account as you would any other user.

Service accounts are like dummy users, they have their own drive account.  However in order for a service account to access a file it must be preauthorized.  In other words you must configure permission before you use it.

Comment: perfect, thanks for explaining that! It was a matter of #2, the file needed to be shared with the service account